# Setting environments on Vagrant?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I'd like to ask some information about Vagrant.

First things first,  my PC runs Windows as the main OS, I'm using VirtualBox and I've installed VirtualBox in which I've created a virtual where I've installed Ubuntu and set up my development environement (Ruby-MySQL-Git-Nodejs etc), but I'd like to see whether is better option to switch to Vagrant or keep things as currently are.

Now, regarding Vagrant. From a little research I've done about why using Vagrant most resources say that it gives you the ability to create a virtual development environment same as the production. Also, by installing Vagrant you can set up a virtual  Linux environment on every OS either Windows, or Mac or Linux too.

So far so good but my main question is can I use Vagrant for creating multiple development environments? so for example:

1. Have n-different development environments: **A** for Ruby (Ruby - Rails - Postgres - Git - Nodejs) and **B** for PHP (PHP-MySQL-Git). So if you try in **B** the `ruby -v` or `node -v` commands they won't be identified as installed in this one.
2. Usually on a development environment there's a folder where we keep all projects, like `projects/project-a`, `projects/project-b`, `projects/project-c` etc etc. Can I have different/separate environements for each project, even if both project-a and project-b are PHP projects? So basically I want to keep them separate and clean from each other to avoid any mess and conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! I love Vagrant even though it doesn't do much, but it makes it convenient. Just keep a `Vagrantfile` in each of your `project-a`... folders and they will be separate machines. You can have ones for Rails, for PHP, etc.

Here are existing ones for Rails: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=rails

For PHP: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=php

To bring up a dev environment (presumably with server), just type

```
vagrant init leopard/rwtrusty64
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

Super simple and reproducible. Check the docs for more. https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/

Even better, you can install Vagrant and VirtualBox with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), just like `yum` or `apt-get` or `emerge`.

```
chocolatey install virtualbox
chocolatey install vagrant
```

Comment: Is it better to have Linux as my main OS, or works exactly same no matter what the main OS is? Also can I set it up on my (virtual machine) Ubuntu os so I can have all dev environments there?

Comment: It works the same no matter the main OS. That's the benefit. If you have a virtual machine inside a virtual machine, that will get complicated, slower, and have possible problems. I'm sure it's possible, but not sure if VirtualBox can do that - have not tried.